# What is the name of the technique where an article quotes itself in large text?

Tags: typography

This technique comes from print media, and I'm sure that if I'd ever taken a typography class I'd know it.  I tried googling but couldn't find anything helpful.

What is it called when an article quotes itself and places that quote in large text in the middle of the page?

I found an example [in this article on the history of HTML 5](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/general/a-brief-history-of-html5/).  See the text circled in red:

---

[image: Example of article quoted in middle of itself in large text]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are called ["pull quotes"](http://desktoppub.about.com/od/glossary/g/Pull-Quote.htm)

> Used to attract attention, especially in long articles, a **pull-quote** is a small selection of text *pulled out and quoted* in a larger typeface or using some other formatting distinct from the rest of the article. A pull-quote may be framed by rules, placed within the article, span multiple columns, or be placed in an empty column near the article.

It is also sometimes known as a call-out, but not all call-outs are pull-quotes.

There's no specific element in html5 for pull-quotes, you would likely code them as an [`<aside>` or a `<blockquote>`](http://www.impressivewebs.com/aside-vs-blockquote-html5/), Semantically, they would likely be an `<aside>`, since you should be able to remove them without the remaining content becoming incomplete.

Ideally you'd also [code them so the content of the pull-quote doesn't appear as text in the content](http://miekd.com/articles/pull-quotes-with-html5-and-css/).

Comment: In html5 would you use figure, aside or/and blockquote?

Comment: @jrosell: I was thinking of using a div with a custom class so I could duplicate the text using something like jQuery.  I'll look into those tho.  And I'll let Erics actually answer ;)

Comment: How do we distinguish between when the quote is also present in the body text and when it only in the quote?  Sometimes, a small part of the text is itself formatted in a distinctive way to make it appear more prominently, entirely as in the above example.

Comment: I see your edit +1